# jQuery Move Element Then Pin it and Move it horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to accomplish the effects on [this site](http://everylastdrop.co.uk/), but I only need to move around a few things based on scrolling. My goal is for the basketball to go into the box, then after scrolling down a little bit the box goes onto the truck and the objects all go together horizontally across the page. Also, I want this to happen when you scroll down, not when you scroll up like in the current fiddle.

Here my current [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sVzfx/35/), originally based on this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sVzfx/6/). Below is the js.

```
  var fixedElement = false;
  var changingMoment = 150;
$(window).scroll(function() {
// floatingContentMark lets us know where the element shall change from fixed to relative
// and vice versa
 var distanceFromTop = $("#floatingContentMark").offset().top - $(this).scrollTop();    
   if ((distanceFromTop <= changingMoment && !fixedElement) || 
    (distanceFromTop >= changingMoment && fixedElement)) 
     {    // either we came from top or bottom, same function is called
      fixedElement = !fixedElement;
     $('#box').trigger('fixElement');
     }
  });

 $('#box').bind('fixElement', function() {
  if ($(this).css('position') != 'fixed') {
    $(this).css('position', 'fixed') ;
    $(this).css('top', changingMoment) ;
}
else {
    $(this).css('position', 'relative') ;
    $(this).css('top', 'auto') ;
}
}) ;
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question, or are you expecting us to write the rest of the code for you?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your project will be a lot easier if you use a framework or jQuery  Plugin for custom/parallax scrolling. A quick google search brings up several that will easily do what you want:

- [skrollr](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/)
- [scrollorama](http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrollorama/)
- [scrollpath](http://joelb.me/scrollpath/)
- [sequence.js](http://www.sequencejs.com/)
- [stellar.js](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/)
- [scrolly](http://lab.victorcoulon.fr/javascript/scrolly/)
- [NikeBetterWorld](http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/demos/recreate-nikebetterworld-parallax/)
- [Scrolling Parallax](http://jonraasch.com/blog/scrolling-parallax-jquery-plugin)
- [jarallax](http://www.jarallax.com/demo3/)
- [superscrollarama](http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/)

For some inspiration, check out the pages listed [here](http://www.queness.com/post/12637/create-your-own-trendy-parallax-website-layout).